# Is there any way to Programmatically hide "AM" from AM/PM dropdown in MUI DesktopTimePicker?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-date-picker

I'm creating a time range and encountered this issue.
I want to allow only AM when certain condition is true otherwise both AM/PM should be available

I'm using this
https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/desktop-time-picker/

Let me know if you guys can help.

Thanks

I've tried disabling the later time but it still shows AM

`shouldDisableTime={(timeValue, clockType) => { return clockType === "hours" && new Date(timeValue).getHours() >= 12; }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution,
I've used CSS to hide PM with `display:none`.

here how I've achieved it:

first I've created a class:

```
.hide-pm li[aria-label="PM"] {
    display: none;
}
```

then used this class in popper props.

```
<DesktopTimePicker
  ampm
  label='closing time'
  slotProps={
   popper: {
     className: ifTrue ? 'hide-pm' : ''
   }
  }
  ...
/>
```

That's it.

Thanks